# how to access zoomed pdf page in php or html

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick

I am converting pdf to image using imagmagik n php. but having with 100% resolution image quailty is poor. so that i want to access pdf in 200% resolution. please help me out..

Comment: I converted pdf to png using imagemagik and php.

Comment: Is there any specific reason for the 'sql-server-2008' tag?

Comment: no..not any relation for sql server tag..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this help you? Just Googled it - using the `-density` option

http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=10928#p34799